# Track an object velocity in a 2D plane

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, velocity, displacement, camera

I would like to track the motion (actually, I am more interested in the velocity) of an object in a 2D plane (typically 4m x 4m). The object speed is typically 10cm/s, but the mouvement may be chaotic (no predictible pattern). Additionally, the object may rotate.

I've thought of several options but they all have a problem :

**IMU :**
An IMU can be mounted on my object, but pure-IMU tracking is challenging due to the bias in the accelerometer, that leads to a huge error after integration when time flows.

**UWB :**
UWB technology permits to track the object position, so I could obtain the object's velocity by derivative. However, UWB suffers from noise due to non line-of-sight conditions that can happen in my application.

**Fusion IMU/UWB :**
This is for now the best option to my point of view, the IMU's drift being corrected by regular UWB measurements. But it is a bit heavy to implement.

If someone has some ideas to track an object velocity in a 2D plane, it would be great !

Thanks in advance,

Ettore